# Tablix in a RDLC report with fixed height

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a tablix inside a rectangle at middle of my report and when it grows in rows, the page grows too and borders fall in another page. How can I set the tablix to fill it's rows just until rectangle's borders?

Comment: What exactly means "when it grows in rows"? Does it mean you get more rows due to having more rows in the underlying data or does it mean the row height increased for example because of line breaks / longer text values?  I am not sure what problem you solved here and if I have the same or not.

Answer (score 1):

On textboxes on Tablix, Rightclick and goto `TextBox Properties`, in Sizing Options uncheck `Allow height to increase`.